# Upgrading Xcode and Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode3.2

If I already have XCode and IB installed on my system, if I download the newest version and install it, does it automatically upgrade me to the newest version, or do I have to uninstall the old versions first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will just upgrade your existing version unless you change the install location to something other than the default, in which case you can have multiple versions installed. You get to decide this at install time.